# Как сделать кирилический url если стоит плагин для транслитерации (Cyr to Lat reloaded)?

Tags: php, wordpress, функции

Суть плагина я думаю понимают все, он переводит все кириллические слова в латинские буквы, но так понадобилось что нужно получить ссылку именно с кириллическими буквами, как это можно обойти благодаря файлу function, возможно ли прописать кодом
 php для id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В плагине есть единственный хук, который можно использовать. Это `wbcr_ctl_transliterate`. Можно проверять, какой был начальный заголовок поста и возвращать его, если он совпадает с заданным (в примере это `пост 6`).

```
function wbcr_ctl_transliterate_filter( $title, $origin_title, $iso9_table ) {
    if ( 'пост 6' === $origin_title ) {
        return $origin_title;
    }

    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'wbcr_ctl_transliterate', 'wbcr_ctl_transliterate_filter', 10, 3 );
```

Код работает на этапе создания поста. После создания поста можно изменить его slug (постоянную ссылку) на `пост 6` и это значение не будет конвертировано плагином в латинницу.

Comment: Ого костыляка, так айди не известен сначала. Может как то бы кнопкой какой то?

Comment: Это не костыль, а нормальный хук. При чём тут id? Зачем именно id? Знаете, какое будет название поста - ну и вставьте его в код. Кстати, если после создания поста захотите изменить его slug (url), то код тоже сработает. Надо ввести в поле slug `пост 6` и это значение останентся неизменным.

Comment: Я может не догоняю, но в 'пост 6' мне нужно записать 'post=6' или другое число?

Comment: Все я понял как это работает, но возможно ли его в админку как то ввести например поле специальное?

Comment: Возможно все. Но для этого надо сформулировать требования четко и задать отдельный вопрос

Comment: Упс, удалил последние два комента. Работают

Comment: Вопрос изменен [предыдущий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/934692/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-url-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-polylang)