# Как отключить транслитерацию url при использовании polylang?

Tags: wordpress, url, кириллица

Стоит плагин [Cyr-To-Lat](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cyr2lat/)
и polylang

Как сделать что бы при создании новой записи или редактировании, в зависимости от выбраного языка отключался плагин Cyr-To-Lat, например выбрали мы страницу c ua языком [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**и в этот момент отключаем плагин Cyr-To-Lat или транслитерацию url**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой именно плагин, их несколько. Дайте ссылку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В плагин `Cyr-To-Lat` мы сегодня добавили фильтр `ctl_pre_sanitize_title`, который позволяет решить проблему. Этот фильтр должен вернуть значение второго аргумента, чтобы `Cyr-To-Lat` не проводил транслитерацию. Внутри хука можно проверить значение текущего языка. Вот рабочий пример кода:

```
/**
 * Filter Cyr-To-Lat post title.
 *
 * @param bool $flag
 * @param string $title
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
function ctl_pre_sanitize_title_filter( $flag, $title ) {
    if ( 'uk' === pll_current_language() ) {
        return $title;
    }

    return $flag;
}

add_filter( 'ctl_pre_sanitize_title', 'ctl_pre_sanitize_title_filter', 10, 2 );
```

Данный код успешно протестирован с классическим редактором.

К сожалению, при работе с блочным редактором Polylang возвращает false вместо кода языка, что делает невозможным использование этого фильтра с блочным редактором и Гутенберг - посты будут транслитерированы вне зависимости от языка.

Правильный код языка при сохранении поста в блочном редакторе возвращает только WPML. Вот протестированный пример фильтра для WPML + Cyr-To-Lat:

```
/**
 * Filter Cyr-To-Lat post title.
 *
 * @param bool $flag
 * @param string $title
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
function ctl_pre_sanitize_title_filter( $flag, $title ) {
    if ( 'uk' === wpml_get_current_language() ) {
        return $title;
    }

    return $flag;
}

add_filter( 'ctl_pre_sanitize_title', 'ctl_pre_sanitize_title_filter', 10, 2 );
```

Последнюю версию плагина Cyr-To-Lat с упомянутым фильтром пока что можно скачать только с [GitHub](https://github.com/mihdan/cyr2lat).

Comment: Я залил версию 3.4 на wp.org - можно обновиться прямо из админки.

Comment: Я бы поставил 100 голосов сразу!

Comment: Это нужно polylang заставить отдавать нужный язык??

Comment: @AndriiSoldatenko 100 голосов не надо)), но можете отзыв на плагин Cyr-To-Lat написать на сайте wp.org))

Comment: @AndriiSoldatenko вряд ли что-то получится сделать с polylang. Возможно, позже его разработчики поправят функционирование с блочным редактором.

Comment: Так может тогда кнопкой сделать? Или нужно что бы значение было как то установлено заранее, как вы писали уже по этому поводу.

Comment: Да хоть константой в том же самом фильтре. Я не знаю, чего вы хотите добиться и при каких условиях, поэтому точнее ответить сложно.

Comment: Почему я спросил за полиленг, дело в том что я имею два языка на сайте, и для тестов по сео решил проверить как будут себя вести ссылки на кириллице и на латинице, но так получается что плагин для транслитерации все равно нужен. И хочется сделать что бы транслитерация для украинского языка не срабатывала.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88612/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-andrii-soldatenko).

Comment: Я вам в чат написал!

Comment: На украинском[prnt.sc/majyck а вот после публикации prnt.sc/majyy4